# How did the Paladins catch Jumpers before the discovery of electricity?

Tags: jumper

In Jumpers, we learn that the Paladins have been chasing and killing Jumpers "since medieval times".

Paladins' weapons use electricity to disrupt the ability of Jumpers to jump, how did they manage to catch Jumpers before the discovery of electricity (killing them is the easy part as the early part of the film demonstrates)?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the *Paladins* were created for the film, [they are not in original book](http://www.avclub.com/articles/book-vs-film-jumper,2178/).

Comment: @Oliver_C - very interesting link, thanks. The review does mention that a prequel book "Jumper: Griffin's Story", released a year before the film, introduces the Paladins. Updated the question to be clearer, asking about catching rather than killing Jumpers.

Comment: Contrary to popular opinion, the use of electricity for technology is not something that resulted from Ben Franklin's kite episode. There is glaring evidence that "ancient" Egyptians used electricity way back in the days before 2,000 B.C. The "mainstream" education system LIES to you about everything. But the use of electricity in technology is the only thing I care to enlighten you about at this time. Granted, Jumper is a Euro-centric movie (and the European continent did suffer from "stupidia" in medieval times), so the argument of the OP is valid in that regard.

Comment: @Kelton While that might be true (I don't know, though), can you make that sound less like some kind of new age conspiracy theory (but maybe my "mainstream" education is just clouding my judgement here)? ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendera_light seems to indicate that Egyptian usage of electricity is not a common hypothesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3rd book: [Jumper: Griffin's Story, reviewed here](http://www.sfsignal.com/archives/2008/02/review_jumper_and_griffins_story_by_steven_gould/), released just before the film, incorporates more of the film's elements, most notably the Paladins (who weren't in the first 2 books).

This reveals that some Paladins can sense Jumpers if they're nearby when they jump.
In medieval times when towns, villages and populations were a lot smaller and without modern technology, this ability would have been crucial.

Answer (score 4):

The instrument that they use is relatively new. It's understood that not all methods have existed as long as the Paladin fellowship. Their sole purpose is not to stop jumpers using that machine, but just to catch them and kill them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, sneak up behind them and slit their throats. Jumpers don't necessarily know who is a Paladin. For some reason, Roland found it necessary to have a conversation with David in his apartment, instead of just stabbing him to death before David ever saw him.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Hope you enjoy it here. But is there any chance you could elaborate on your answer - how you came to this conclusion, etc? (If you can citing sources/moments in the movie that illustrate your answer, etc., that would be super helpful.) Thanks!